# Wait for two async methods to complete

Tags: objective-c, ios7

I'd like to init a model, let the model do some async stuff and present a new viewcontroller once completed. But how do i wait for the two async methods to be completed and how do I setup the callback method?

***Pseudocode***

In my StartViewController.m:

```
-(void)openArticle
{
  article = [Article initWithObject:someObject];
  article.callback = changeView;
}

-(void)changeView
{
 [self presentViewController:someController];
}
```

In my ArticleModel.m:

```
-(void)initWithObject:someObject
{
  [self loadImage]
  [self geoCode]
}

-(void)loadImage
{
  runAsyncMethod: success:^()  // This one is actually a AFNetworking setImageWithURLRequest
}

-(void)geoCode
{
  runAnotherAsyncMethod: success:^() // This one is actually a geocodeAddressString operation
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve this using `dispatch_group`s

```
- (void)initWithObject:(id)someObject
{
  self = [super init];
  if (self) {
    self.dispatch_group = dispatch_group_create();

    [self loadImage]
    [self geoCode]

    dispatch_group_notify(self.dispatch_group, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
      NSLog(@"Push new view controller");
    });
  }
  return self;
}

- (void)loadImage
{
  dispatch_group_enter(self.dispatch_group);

  __weak __typeof(self) weakSelf = self;
  runAsyncMethod: success:^{
    __typeof(weakSelf) strongSelf = weakSelf;
    if (strongSelf.dispatch_group) {
      dispatch_group_leave(strongSelf.dispatch_group); // You need to ensure that this is called in both success and failure
    }
  }

}

- (void)geoCode
{
  dispatch_group_enter(self.dispatch_group);

  __weak __typeof(self) weakSelf = self;
  runAnotherAsyncMethod: success:^{
    __typeof(weakSelf) strongSelf = weakSelf;
    if (strongSelf.dispatch_group) {
      dispatch_group_leave(strongSelf.dispatch_group);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: bonus points for avoiding the retain cycle by referencing self as a `__weak` variable

Comment: Thanks. But how do I handle errors if one of my AsyncMethod fails? Cause at the moment dispatch_group_notify() is called on success and failure.

Answer (score 1):

You do *not* wait. If you wait, it isn't asynchronous! You would be losing the entire point of asynchronous if you were to wait.

What you do is, when your `success` handler is called, you step out to the main thread (just in case you got called back on a background thread) and now do whatever you need to do. In other words, you just let your `success` handler get called whenever it happens to get called.

In your case, you might like to chain the things you want to do:

- Call `loadImage`
- In its callback, call `geoCode`
- In its callback, step out to the main thread and present the new view controller.

Comment: You might want to launch two requests asynchronously to gain a little time. Having two requests launching async allows him to not wait for one method and the other. Of course that works if they're completely unrelated and not complimentary.

Comment: Yes, @jbouaziz, but I just didn't want to get into the complexities of `dispatch_group`. I'm glad you added an answer showing that!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `dispatch_group` so that when a method is over, it just leaves the group. I use a similar code myself and it works like a charm.

```
- (void)initWithObject:someObject {

    // Create a dispatch group
    dispatch_group_t group = dispatch_group_create();
    [self loadImageWithDispatchGroup:group];
    [self geoCodeWithDispatchGroup:group];

    // Here we wait for all the requests to finish
    dispatch_group_notify(group, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        // Do whatever you need to do when all requests are finished
    });
}

- (void)loadImageWithDispatchGroup:(dispatch_group_t)group {
    dispatch_group_enter(group);
     runAsyncMethod: success:^()  // This one is actually a AFNetworking setImageWithURLRequest
    // In your success or failure AFNetworking method, call this as soon as the request ended
    dispatch_group_leave(group);
}

- (void)geoCodeWithDispatchGroup:(dispatch_group_t)group {
    dispatch_group_enter(group);
    runAnotherAsyncMethod: success:^() // This one is actually a geocodeAddressString operation
    // In your success async geocode callback method, call this as soon as the request ended
    dispatch_group_leave(group);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not known your needs but native GCD way to wait several asynch tasks is

```
void dispatch_barrier_async(dispatch_queue_t queue, dispatch_block_t block);
```

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Performance/Reference/GCD_libdispatch_Ref/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/dispatch_barrier_async